# Rabbi Akiva Eiger symbols in the Oz Vehadar Rif?

Tags: rif-rabbi-isaac-alfasi

I noticed some symbols in the Oz Vehadar Rif that look exactly like the symbols in the Gemara that direct you to the Gilyon Hashas (the "do not enter" symbols).  I can't figure out what they refer to.  Everything on the page is either "Rashi", the Ran, the Baal Hamaor/Milchamos, or lettered notes.  The yalkut mefarshim al harif doesn't seem to have notes corresponding to these symbols.

Maybe I'm missing something obvious, but where those symbols directing me?

Comment: Can you give an example location of such a mark?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It marks a new page in the traditional pagination of the Rif, which is different from the pagination in the Oz Vehadar edition.

From the דבר אל הלומד before the Rif:

> במהדורתנו, שונים מנין הדפים וצורתם מאשר ברי"ף מהדורת וילנא. כדי להקל על המעיין להשוות בין מהדורתנו למהדורת וילנא, רשמנו את חלוקת הדפים של הרי"ף מהדורת וילנא בראש כל עמוד ברווח שבין הרי"ף והר"ן (=תחת ארבע השורות הרחבות של פי' הר"ן שבראש כל עמוד), וכן על שולי גיליון הרי"ף והר"ן, ובפנים במקום התחלפות הדפים צוין בסימן כזה ∅

(I wrote ∅ in place of the actual symbol used, which is the one that usually points to Gilyon Hashas.)

There are a lot of different paginations for the Rif. For instance, it should be noted that when the Ein Mishpat refers to a page number in the Rif, it's a totally different page from the Vilna edition, and isn't marked in the Oz Vehadar edition.

Comment: Thanks!   The thing that really threw me off is one of them was in a place where it would actually make sense for R' Akiva Eiger to comment.  I was excited that I had figured out in advance what he was going to say.  Oh well.